# Use pg_cron to run VACUUM on multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-cron

Reading the pg_cron [documentation](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) I saw that the examples only execute a command when scheduling a task.

In a StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347385/full-vacuum-multible-table-in-pg-cron) I saw that a user tried to run multiple VACUUM when scheduling the task, but an error occurs.

Is there a way to run VACUUM on multiple tables in sequence using pg_cron? There are about 112 selected tables that must be vacuumed, out of a total of 155, so scheduling a task for each one is not very practical.

Or for example, delete old records from a table and immediately at the end of the process run cron on selected tables?

Comment: A much better approach is to configure autovacuum to be more aggressive so that you don't need to run `vacuum` manually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've already worked with an aggressive configuration for AutoVacuum and AutoAnalyze. The result was a catastrophe, the autovacuum occurred so frequently that the database ended up being unavailable for use, as the tables in my database tend to have several modifications per day.

Comment: @Tom, that objection doesn't make much sense, autovacuum doesn't lock out data modifications, and neither schema modifications except when doing it for wraparound; and wraparound vacuums are not controlled by the normal autovac aggressiveness knobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vacuum a list of tables in one command.

```
vacuum FULL pgbench_accounts, pgbench_history, pgbench_branches, pgbench_tellers;
```

But hopefully you are not really doing FULL, that would almost surely be a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why running `VACUUM FULL` is considered a mistake generally? Because the DB wasn't configured properly to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

VACUUM FULL would lock the table until complete. Use: `VACUUM (PARALLEL 3)  schema_name.table_name`

Comment: For future visitors,  please explain what it does, what the parameters mean etc.